# Symfony 2.1 - Creating authentication listener with JMS\DiExtraBundle

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

I have created the following listener:

```php
<?php
namespace KekRozsak\SecurityBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

/**
 * @DI\Service
 * @DI\Tag("kernel.event_listener", attributes={"event" = "security.authentication.success"})
 */
class AuthSuccess implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * The Doctrine interface
     *
     * @var Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface $doctrine
     *
     * @DI\Inject
     */
    private $doctrine;

    public function onSecurityAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $em = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager();
        $user->setLastLoginAt(new \DateTime('now'));
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        $em = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager();
        $user->setLastLoginAt(new \DateTime('now'));
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't get called. If I inject it with

```xml
    <service id="kek_rozsak_security.auth.success" class="KekRozsak\SecurityBundle\Security\AuthSuccess">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine" />
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.authentication.success" />
    </service>
```

And add the constructor:

```php
public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine)
{
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}
```

It runs like charm. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you remember to set all_bundles true, or explicitly configure this bundle to use the annotations? Should be set in your config.yml.

Comment: No, but just found that. I write my answer to my noobness in a minute... :S

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own (kinda noob) question...

I simply forgot to add

```
jms_di_extra:
    locations:
        all_bundles: false
        bundles: [ KekRozsakFrontBundle, KekRozsakSecurityBundle ]
        directories: [ "%kernel.root_dir%/../src" ]
```

to my `config.yml`